# Unsupported Operation exception in java

Tags: java

I am getting the exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet

Code is

```
 private static void mode(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private static void quality(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private static void complexity(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private static void sampleRate(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
public static void main(final String[] args)
     {
      mode(0);
      quality(1);
      complexity(1);
      sampleRate(8000);
    JSpeexEnc encoder = new JSpeexEnc();
    if (encoder.parseArgs(args, FILE_FORMAT_WAVE)) {
      encoder.encode();

    }
```

Please tell me why this exception is coming...

Comment: If you comment the `throw new ...` lines, no exceptions will be thrown.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Please tell is this anything wrong in the code that this exception is coming.. Please correct me....

Comment: seems these are some sort of auto generated methods, you need to provide your own implementations (what you want the methods to do).

Comment: If this is homework or something like that, you should delete those lines and implement those methods.

Comment: please tell is my code is correct and passing values in methd in main function is correct or not because exception is coming..

Comment: share minimal testable code.

Comment: just remove all the  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); and u will not get it. :)

Comment: please suggset why this exception is coming.. is there anything wrong in the code

Comment: every thing is syntactically correct, but when you do  `mode(0);` what do you expect to happen with `0` or anything else if the mode is `0`. with default implementation the method call will always throw `UnsupportedOperationException`    with message `Not Supported`, indicating that you can't use the method (may be unless you provide some logic there).

Answer (score 1):

you are calling methods that `throws UnsupportedOperationException.`

```
private static void mode(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

private static void quality(int i) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

private static void complexity(int i) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

private static void sampleRate(int i) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

replace with

```
private static void mode(int i) {
         //what you want to do
    }

    private static void quality(int i) {
        //what you want to do
    }

    private static void complexity(int i) {
        //what you want to do
    }

    private static void sampleRate(int i) {
         //what you want to do
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
```

is the cause of the exception. Which means, whenever this method is called, it throws the exception, as you have defined it!

Answer (score 0):

You can also handle the exception in main method to avoid the program throwing the exception. Something like this -:

private static void mode(int i) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

```
    private static void quality(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private static void complexity(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private static void sampleRate(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
public static void main(final String[] args)
     {
    try
    {
      mode(0);
      quality(1);
      complexity(1);
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }


     }
```